# How to uninstall a Windows Update (patch) in silent mode using terminal or PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, terminal, uninstall, patch

Tried using `wusa /uninstall /kb:4497464 /quiet`, but from Windows 10 they have deprecated the `quiet` flag. Is there any other way to uninstall?

Answer (score 2):

This feature was deprecated and the ability to uninstall updates in quiet mode was removed. Refer to
[Windows 10 deprecated features](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-10-deprecated-features)
which says

> The wusa usage to quietly uninstall an update has been deprecated. The uninstall command with /quiet switch fails with event ID 8 in the Setup event log. Uninstalling updates quietly could be a security risk because malicious software could quietly uninstall an update in the background without user intervention.

Using PowerShell, run the following command to find the identifier of the
update:

```
dism /online /get-packages /format:table | findstr /i "package_for"
```

[image]

To actually remove it:

```
Get-WindowsPackage -Online -PackageName "{PACKAGE-NAME}" |Remove-WindowsPackage -Online -NoRestart -Verbose
```

Source:
[unable to use wusa to uninstall updates in quiet mode on server 2016/2019. older os removal works](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/636329/unable-to-use-wusa-to-uninstall-updates-in-quiet-m.html).

Answer (score 0):

powershell script:

```
(dism /online /get-packages /format:table) | ForEach-Object {
$tmp=$_ ;
$tmpArr=$tmp.Split("|") ;
if ( $tmpArr.Length -eq 4 )
{
$tmpName=$tmpArr[0].Trim(" ") ;
$tmpType=$tmpArr[2].Trim(" ") ;
if ( $tmpType.ToLower().Contains("update") )
{
Write-Host "--- delete. |$tmpName| . |$tmpType|" ;
Get-WindowsPackage -Online -PackageName "$tmpName" | Remove-WindowsPackage -Online -NoRestart -Verbose ;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).